# How to handle sse connection closed?

Tags: spring-boot, server-sent-events, project-reactor, spring-session

I have an endpoint streamed as in the sample code block. When streaming, I call an async method through `streamHelper.getStreamSuspendCount()`. I am stopping this async method in changing state. But I can not access this async method when the browser is closed and the session is terminated. I am stopping the async method in session scope when changing state. But I can not access this async method when the browser is closed and the session is terminated. How can I access this scope when Session is closed?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stream/{columnId}/suspendCount", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Flux<Integer> suspendCount(@PathVariable String columnId) {
    ColumnObject columnObject = streamHelper.findColumnObjectInListById(columnId);
    return streamHelper.getStreamSuspendCount(columnObject);
}


getStreamSuspendCount(ColumnObject columnObject) {
   ...
   //async flux
   Flux<?> newFlux = beSubscribeFlow.get(i);
   Disposable disposable = newFlux.subscribe();
   beDisposeFlow.add(disposable); // my session scope variable. if change state, i will kill disposable (dispose()).
   ...
   return Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> columnObject.getPendingObject().size())).distinctUntilChanged()
                    .doOnNext(i -> {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that you are attempting to get a `Disposable` that you want to call at the end of the session. But in doing so, you are subscribing to the sequence yourself. Spring Framework will also subscribe to the `Flux` returned by `getStreamSuspendCount`, and it is THAT subscription that needs to be cancelled for the SSE client to get notified.

Now how to achieve this? What you need is a sort of "valve" that will cancel its source upon receiving an external signal. This is what `takeUntilOther(Publisher<?>)` does.

So now you need a `Publisher<?>` that you can tie to the session lifecycle (more specifically the session close event): as soon as it emits, `takeUntilOther` will cancel its source.

2 options there:

- the session close event is exposed in a listener-like API: use `Mono.create`
- you really need to manually trigger the cancel: use `MonoProcessor.create()` and when the time comes, push any value through it

Here are simplified examples with made up APIs to clarify:

### Create

```
return theFluxForSSE.takeUntilOther(Mono.create(sink ->
    sessionEvent.registerListenerForClose(closeEvent -> sink.success(closeEvent))
));
```

### MonoProcessor

```
MonoProcessor<String> processor = MonoProcessor.create();
beDisposeFlow.add(processor); // make it available to your session scope?
return theFluxForSSE.takeUntilOther(processor); //Spring will subscribe to this
```

Let's simulate the session close with a scheduled task:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(() ->
    processor.onNext("STOP") // that's the key part: manually sending data through the processor to signal takeUntilOther
, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here is a simulated unit test example that you can run to better understand what happens:

```
@Test
public void simulation() {
    Flux<Long> theFluxForSSE = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100));

    MonoProcessor<String> processor = MonoProcessor.create();
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(() -> processor.onNext("STOP"), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    theFluxForSSE.takeUntilOther(processor.log())
                 .log()
                 .blockLast();
}
```

Comment: I understand. Thanks for answer Simon.